# Updating system drivers on Win 8

Tags: drivers, windows-update, updates, software-update

I hope this isn't the wrong place to ask this, but if it is I apologize ahead and will close the thread ASAP.

I have an Asus G73Jw with Windows 8.1 and I was looking into make it run faster/more smoothly. For this, besides other things (windows update for instance), I was looking into updating the drivers on my laptop. Going to Asus' website I notice that the some of the most recent drivers date back 4 years. So I thought that the best way is to go, component by component, to the provider's website and download the latest drivers. For the graphics card this was easy. But going one by one will take some time...

So my question is: which components would you say that should be updated most often in order for the computer to run faster/smoother?

Comment: There likely isn't any drivers newer than 4 years ago expect the Nvidia driver on Nvidias website

Comment: I wonder why people are demoting this question... If there is something wrong I'd love to fix it! If it shouldn't be open, I'll close it! But simply demoting it and not saying why will not tell me what I did wrong...

Comment: Your asking an opinion on which device drivers you should update you can only update a driver of a newer driver is released most device drivers are not updated very often, opinion questions, are not on top pic here at Superuser

Comment: I'm not asking which is the best software to run the updates for me or anything that is highly subjective, just which drivers have the most impact on system performance. I believe my question allows for very specific answers, but I'll be happy to delete this question anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, getting drivers directly from the chip vendor's web site is absolutely the best way to go.  The drivers that computer manufacturers post on their web site are almost always either old, or sometimes flat-out wrong.

However, continually updating your drivers will not really make your computer perform faster.  The only exception to this rule is your video driver.  AMD/ATI and nVidia update their drivers almost monthly it seems.  The updates are usually to support games and not really performance enhancements.

Otherwise, you should only really ever have to update your drivers when you're having a problem, as most manufacturers only release new drivers to either support new models or to fix a bug that may not affect you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm torn between two answers...

1. IOBit's freeware  [Driver Booster](http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php) for quick & easy...

or

2. Don't bother with anything except Graphics Drivers, direct from AMD/NVidia/Intel as the rest probably isn't worth it on a 4-year-old machine.

Comment: IOBit's software is shovelware, and does nothing, you cannot do better by hand,

Comment: It's quick, it's easy - on a 4-year-old machine it's unlikely to come up with anything spectacular - that was my point. (I'm assuming one comma too many in your reply, btw.)

Comment: 4 years, such a long time huh... sad :(  thanks! I'll wait a bit more for some possible answer before accepting one!

Comment: You can do better by hand* driver software like that id useless